# LDAP Search Filter Syntax (ONLY) to Identify Objects in a Specific OU (AD)

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query, adsi

Many of the non-LDAP-specific applications that interface with AD (e.g. apps that read in objects or use AD for auth) allow only for specifying an LDAP search filter.  The problem with this though is that I can't limit the query anything below the default domain partition level (at least, AFAIK).

In an attempt to address this, I was trying search filters like:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(distinguishedname=*,OU=MyNamedOU,DC=*))
```

...however, after it didn't work, I started finding articles about how you can't query based on distinguishedname as it's a constructed attribute.

***Regardless, is there a way to limit a query to a specific OU based just in the Search Filter syntax alone?***

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Active Directory does not allow you to search a partial match on `distinguishedName`. If `distinguishedName` is in the query, it can only be an exact match. This is true of any attribute that takes a `distinguishedName`, like `manager`, `member`, etc.

There really is no way to limit a query to a specific OU by the query string alone, since there is no searchable attribute that has the OU. If you want to search only specific OUs, you will either need to:

1. Search a single OU by setting the [`SearchRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.searchroot) (sometimes called "search base") to that OU rather than the whole domain. You can also set the [`SearchScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.searchscope) to `SearchScope.OneLevel` to not search sub-OUs if you want. Repeat the search for every OU you want to include. Or,
2. Search the top-most OU with the results you want, loop through the results, and discard the ones in the OU's you don't want by looking at the `distinguishedName`. (since you already have the results at this point, the `distinguishedName` is just a string you can do whatever you want with, including a partial match)

The second option will usually be faster since it means one search against AD instead of multiple, but it depends on how many results you end up with and how many you're discarding.

Comment: +1 - This is likely the answer and the one I expected but I'm going to reserve selecting your answer in hopes someone else has a hack to address this.  My problem is that most applications that provide a way to query LDAP typically only expose the 'Filter' property to specify--not the SearchRoot or SearchScope.  This question is an attempt to see if anyone's gotten around this common limitation in applications.  I'll select this answer assuming someone hasn't cracked this nut.

Comment: Queries can only match against the attributes of the object. So it's easy to confirm. Just look at all the attributes on the object (for example, in the Attribute Editor in AD Users and Computer). The only attribute that has the OU is [`msDS-parentdistname`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adls/85d11f99-0988-4996-97fb-bfa95e0159b2), (introduced in Windows Server 2012), but that's a constructed attribute (calculated at the time you request it), so it cannot be used in a query.

Comment: Good answer, I'd go for option 1 with a client that allows to specify several bases, handling each underlying requests itself, and collecting results as if one single request occurred.

Comment: @thepip3r *"most applications that provide a way to query LDAP typically only expose the 'Filter' property to specify--not the SearchRoot or SearchScope"* that's not true, there must be a *base* to specify and applications can't guess it, the name may vary though, "user base" for authentication, "user group search" for authorization or whatever, any search query require a basedn.